# How to decode a multibyte utf8 string? (C++)

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, decode, multibyte

I'm trying to build a set of helper functions for decoding and modifying multibyte utf-8 strings. For example, finding the amount of characters in the string, and finding the byte offset of a particular character.

I've been looking for a solution for a while, but haven't been able to figure it out.
If anyone could show me a cross platform and portable way to do this only using the STL
I would really appreciate it. Also if there is a c++11 way to do it I'm open to that as well.

Comment: http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: Stack Overflow is for answering _specific questions about problems you actually face with your code_, not doing your code for you

Comment: see utf8everywhere.org instructions

Answer (score 3):

You should read and study the wikipedia page on UTF-8, the encoding is clearly described thereL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

To decode UTF-8, read the first byte, and that should tell you how many subsequent bytes form the character.  Then read in that many other bytes, concatenate the "data" bits, and you'll have the codepoint number.

If you do this until you reach the end of the string, this allows you to calculate how many codepoints are in the string.

If you do this until you reach a certain codepoint index, you'll know the byte offset for that codepoint index.

I don't think there's really any STL features that help with this, other than your basic `std::string::const_iterator`.

As for nonstandard libraries, I *highly* recommend using a unicode library such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), or instead of writing the code yourself.  The .Net libraries kinda sorta work if you're careful, but I don't think Windows has any other APIs that can help with this.